# How to set the internet connection in Xcode5?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode5

I've recently started the iOS development and unfortunatelly, I have not enough money buy Mac and setup a virtual machine. I use XCode 5 version and the app does not work the way I want. I guess a problem the internet connection. But I don't find the solution my problem. Somebody could tell me where I can set under Xcode 5. It's named in XCode 7 NSAppTransportSecurity.
Sorry, poor my English and thanks in advance! :)

Comment: you need to post code and the actual results where the error occurs.

Comment: Have you tried searching the hundreds of previous questions on SO about app transport security problems and how to solve them?